# Hello World example for V8 using gyp

Tags: c++, embedded-v8, gyp

Since SCons has been deprecated. I used the gyp to generate vs solution.
I did what they told me on the build [BuildingWithGYP](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP).
And the v8 project builded ok! 
and I got the v8_base.lib but no v8.lib.

And in the hello world project ,[get started](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/v8/get_started.html).I add the lib directory into the add library.
But it linked failed:

Linking...

```
1>v8test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: 
__thiscall v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope(void)" (?? 
1HandleScope@v8@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main 
1>v8test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: 
__thiscall v8::String::AsciiValue::~AsciiValue(void)" (?? 
1AsciiValue@String@v8@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main 
1>v8test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: 
__thiscall v8::String::AsciiValue::AsciiValue(class v8::Handle<class 
v8::Value>)" (??0AsciiValue@String@v8@@QAE@V?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@2@@Z) 
referenced in function _main 
1>v8test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: 
class v8::Local<class v8::Value> __thiscall v8::Script::Run(void)" (? 
Run@Script@v8@@QAE?AV?$Local@VValue@v8@@@2@XZ) referenced in function 
_main 
……
```

It seems that couldn't find the implement 
but i used the dumpbin tool and find the symbol i can find them in the v8_base.lib

I am sure that the library directory is ok!
but i don't know why it couldn't find the implement.

Comment: Did you build to make shared library or static? If you got shared you should also have v8.lib, or you can alternatively just use GCC/Clang and link directly with dll. v8.lib should be about 200K. If you link to v8_base you also need to link v8_[no]snapshot. I personaly never been able to link v8 static on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the lib "v8_base.lib" as an additional dependency to fix the problem.